# Hierarchical Autosuggest

Tags: search, user-experience, autosuggest

I am designing an autosuggest feature on a quick-search box.  Suggestions will include small icons, multiline text, etc.  The application is handling orders.  The search field will recognize a variety of different meaningful terms - e.g. customer surname, order id, etc.  But when an order ID is input, I want users to get an opportunity to view either the order, or the person.  I was thinking that I would like a hierarchy within the list - so if i type 1234, and it matches 5 orders for 3 different people, the 3 people are returned at the top level, and their 5 orders underneath the respective customer.

Quick mockup:

[image]

Has anyone seen something like this implemented elsewhere?  Don't want to re-invent the wheel.  Also interested in any other feedback.

Comment: That seems like a good way to present that kind of information. The only thing I'd worry about is managing lots and lots of results. Like what if one person has 50 orders, and the other person that also matches only has one? Would you want to list both people? How are you managing scrolling/paging of results?

Comment: Good point.  I think some pagination could be available for the rare occurrences where all I know about an order is the first 4 digits, and I want to go through them all, but an advanced search facility will also be included elsewhere.  So ordering will be important.  Maybe your first person has the first 3 orders listed, and something tell them there are 47 more, leaving room for person number 2.

Comment: Very interesting idea, I haven't seen anything done like it. What you might want to consider, instead of pagination perhaps, is a feature to collapse a given user (the top level), so that if you have the aforementioned 50, but you're not interested in that user, you can collapse all their under-matching records - just a thought, anyway.

Comment: Nice idea - also worth considering.  I'm surprised there's no suggestions of  another site out there that has some degree of hierarchy-based autosuggest.  The closest I can think of is the spotlight search on a mac (or the start search in windows) - results are grouped by type (documents, folders, etc).

Comment: @Ben Packard, based on the mockup you provided, there's only ONE order with ID "23-345..." with five items by three people, is that correct? Or is it supposed to be five orders with different IDs?

Comment: @Gan - yes, it was different order numbers - lazy mockup, sorry

Comment: @Ben, read your comment. Even if they are different order numbers, I still think it is overkill though. Please refer to my answer below and let me have your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your question:** No, haven't seen this elsewhere.

**Feedback on your mockup:**

I would say that it is a pretty creative autosuggest solution.

However, I think it is overkill though. If I just want to quickly navigate to the Order page by searching a specific Order ID (and expecting only one result in the autosuggest), but the autosuggest shows up five order items under three people (as shown in your mockup), I think that is way too much, put aside performance.

**My idea:**

Each autosuggest item contains one *Primary Line* that can clearly identify the item and additional *Details Line*(s) that provide more description about the item, similar to Google's search result page and Facebook search autosuggest.

For example, the autosuggest shows up each item like this when users search for an order:

> **(Order Icon) 23-34534**
>
> Loaf of Bread, Soda and more.
>
> By Bob Jones, Paul Smith and others.

You can make each order item (Loaf of Bread, Soda, more) link to the respective order item line in the Order page, and each person name to the respective person page. This method is more concise and takes less space than your mockup while still providing the functionality that you want.

Sometimes, simple is better, less is more. Remember the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Think of Apple iPod and iPhone as examples.